# value of variable is not being hide during inheritence

Tags: java, inheritance

Very Common: but making me confuse

What I know,method having same declaration being override while variables having same name hides.

```
 class Test1 {
     String dependsOnA="15"; 
 }

 class Beta extends Test1 {
     String dependsOnA="19";
  }


public class Test{
    public static void main(String s[]){
        Test1 beta=new Beta();
        System.out.println(beta.dependsOnA);
    }

}
```

why in my code `Output Is-`

`15`

since value of variable `dependsOnA` `15` has been hide by `19`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always remember that during *inheritance*, *fields are accessed based on reference type* and *overriden methods are accessed based on object type*. Hence, the answer is `15` and not `19` since the reference is of type `Test1`

Answer (score 3):

When you use a variable whose compile type is the type of the super class `Test1` to access `dependsOnA`, you access the variable declared in that super class. The variable being accessed depends on the compile type of the `beta` variable precisely because there's no overriding for variables.

Hiding takes place only when you access `dependsOnA` by a variable whose compile time type is `Beta`.